# Getting "at Error (native)" instead of actual node.js stacktrace despite using err.stack

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

Using the following example code in io.js 3.2.0 64bit on Windows 10 and calling the following code with `node example.js`

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('I_DONT_EXIST', function (/**Error*/ err, /**string[]*/ files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
});
```

I get

```
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '...\I_DONT_EXIST']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '...\\I_DONT_EXIST' }
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '...\I_DONT_EXIST'
    at Error (native)
```

So I get `at Error (native)` instead of the actual error trace even though I ask for `err.stack`.

Shouldn't this be the actual stack trace?

EDIT:

Here is a tiny piece of code that demonstrates my last (3rd) comment to the answer below.

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('I_DONT_EXIST', function (/**Error*/ err, /**string[]*/ files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('\n== 1) Original error');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, Reflect.ownKeys(err), 4));
        console.log('\n== 2) Original error "stack" property');
        console.log(err.stack);

        const e = new Error(err);
        // Copy parameters I'm interested in from the original object
        e.code = err.code;

        console.log('\n\n== 3) New error');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e, Reflect.ownKeys(e), 4));
        console.log('\n== 4) New error "stack" property');
        console.log(e.stack);

        console.log('\n\n== 5) Throw the error');
        throw e;
    }
});
```

The output I get, showing that I don't even get a file location of where the error finally occurs when I examine the original error object but get one in the new one, is:

```
== 1) Original error
{
    "stack": "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\I_DONT_EXIST'",
    "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\I_DONT_EXIST'",
    "errno": -4058,
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "syscall": "scandir",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\xxx\\I_DONT_EXIST"
}

== 2) Original error "stack" property
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\xxx\I_DONT_EXIST'


== 3) New error
{
    "stack": "Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\I_DONT_EXIST'\n    at C:\\Users\\xxx\\test.js:11:19",
    "message": "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\I_DONT_EXIST'",
    "code": "ENOENT"
}

== 4) New error "stack" property
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\xxx\I_DONT_EXIST'
    at C:\Users\xxx\test.js:11:19


== 5) Throw the error
C:\Users\xxx\test.js:20
        throw e;
        ^

Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\xxx\I_DONT_EXIST'
    at C:\Users\xxx\test.js:11:19
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically for async methods there won't be much of a (useful) stack trace available. There are modules like [`longjohn`](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) that can help provide more of a stack trace for such methods, but you wouldn't want to use that in production because of the overhead it incurs.

Comment: Ah that sucks. I tried to work around it by re-throwing the error in the error handler using `throw new Error(err);`, that seems to work. Are there any arguments against this?

Comment: I tried `throw new Error(err)` and got a trace, but it ends with `at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)` so the answer remains... there is no (useful) stack trace.

Comment: True, I don't get the original caller any more, but more than compared to not doing it. If I use the simple example above (using node.js 7.0.0) I don't even get the information about the file location where the error is finally thrown. What I don't understand: I *do* get the location when I let the exception abort the process, but if I look at the error object from inside the code I don't see one. I look at the error object `err` and also at `err.stack`. I assign some properties from the original error object, for example `err.code`, to the new one, just for the record of those reading this.